# Change value of href attribute based on form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a form with 5 inputs:

1. Service type
2. Number of days
3. Number of children
4. Number of adults

and I would like to change the value of a button based on these variables using JavaScript.

So Far This is what i got.

JS

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var servicetype = $("#servicetype").val();
        var service = $("#service").val();
        var adults = $("#adults").val();
        var children = $("#children").val();    
        var days = $("#days").val();
    window.open("https://secure.sample.com/service.aspx?&days="+days"&service="+service"&adults="+adults"&children="+children"&servicetype="+servicetype , '_blank');
    });
});

HTML
```

```html
<select type="hidden"  name="service_type" id="servicetype">
            <option type="hidden"  value="">Select service</option>
            <option type="hidden"  value="AK">Service 1</option>
            <option type="hidden" value="BK">Service 2</option>
            <option type="hidden" value="IK">Service 3</option>
            <option type="hidden" value="HK">Service 4</option>
</select>
            <input type="number" name="days" min="1" id="days">
            <input type="number" name="service" min="1" id="serviceamount">
            <input type="number" min="1" name="adult" id="adults">
            <input type="number" min="0" name="children" id="children">

    <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

I'm pretty new at this so any help would be great. Sorry for the mishap earlier.

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: So what's your problem? What did you try so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Where are the `variables` ? Question seems incomplete...

Comment: Hi Guys, Edited it now. Sorry for the mishap. pretty new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Your mistake was:

1) your variables should read "+foo+" and not just "+foo";

2) the first argument in window.open (i.e. the link) should end with an apostrophe, the same way it started.

tested and working.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var servicetype = $("#servicetype").val();
    var service = $("#service").val();
    var adults = $("#adults").val();
    var children = $("#children").val();
    var days = $("#days").val();
    window.open("https://secure.sample.com/service.aspx?&days="+days+"&service="+service+"&adults="+adults+"&children="+children+"&servicetype="+servicetype+"", "_blank"); 
 });
```